# When I used hive's orc table, I changed the configuration of the thing, but an error was reported

Tags: hive

When my orc table was created, I changed some properties of the table：`tblproperties('transactional'='true')；`

then i try[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6EXK.png)
but it is not ok,it shows

> FAILED: Error in acquiring locks: Error communicating with the
> metastore

I found that if I don't add that statement, I can execute the insert command on the orc table, but cannot execute the update and delete commands. Is there any way to enable the orc table I created to execute these two commands?

I want to know why I get an error when I use these six statements